# How to boost solr results based on rawquerystring when using stemming

Tags: solr, stemming

When using stemming, a search keyword containing plural words, like "cats", is converted to "cat" in Solr parsedquery.

Solr result now contains documents that matched "cat" as well as "cats".

I want to give a higher boost to documents that contain "cats", while other results (that matched "cat", and not "cats") follow these documents with a lower score.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a second field that you dont stemm (you can use copyField to link both fields), then match either of both fields, giving more boost to the unstemmed one